# pytest: robust file path of a txt file used in tests

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, pytest

During a pytest fixture, what is the best way to robustly get the location of a text file for users that may specify different working directories at runtime e.g. I want a person using the cmd line in the test fixture directory find the file as well as an integration server which may work in the project's root. Can I somehow include the text file in a module? What are best practices for including and getting access to non .py files?

I am aware of BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), but I am not sure if this will always refer to the same directory given a particular way of running the test suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` (which is what I think you meant above) worked fine for me so far - it should work as long as Python can figure the path of the file, and with pytest I can't imagine a scenario where that wouldn't be true.